Reshape RuntimeError: shape '[1, 2]' is invalid for input of size 100
I'm building a simple football scores prediction model in Pytorch.
My steps:

clean and process the data
use team names as inputs and scores as outputs
onehot encode team names
pass two team names to the model
add non linearity
(PROBLEM IS HERE) recieve TWO scores as outputs

however my model is returning two scores multiple times
tensor([[0.5232, 0.4844],
        [0.5232, 0.4844],
        [0.5232, 0.4844],
        [0.5232, 0.4844],
        [0.5232, 0.4844],
        [0.5232, 0.4844],
        [0.5232, 0.4844],
        [0.5232, 0.4844],
        [0.5232, 0.4844],
        [0.5232, 0.4844],
        [0.5232, 0.4844],
        [0.5232, 0.4844],
        [0.5232, 0.4844],
        [0.5232, 0.4844],
        [0.5232, 0.4844],
        [0.5232, 0.4844],
        [0.5232, 0.4844],
        [0.5232, 0.4844],
        [0.5232, 0.4844],
        [0.5232, 0.4844],
        [0.5232, 0.4845],
        [0.5232, 0.4844],
        [0.5232, 0.4844],
        [0.5232, 0.4844],
        [0.5232, 0.4844],
        [0.5232, 0.4844],
        [0.5232, 0.4844],
        [0.5232, 0.4844],
        [0.5232, 0.4844],
        [0.5232, 0.4844],
        [0.5232, 0.4844],
        [0.5232, 0.4844],
        [0.5232, 0.4844],
        [0.5232, 0.4844],
        [0.5232, 0.4844],
        [0.5232, 0.4844],
        [0.5232, 0.4844],
        [0.5232, 0.4844],
        [0.5232, 0.4844],
        [0.5232, 0.4844],
        [0.5232, 0.4844],
        [0.5232, 0.4844],
        [0.5232, 0.4844],
        [0.5232, 0.4844],
        [0.5232, 0.4844],
        [0.5232, 0.4844],
        [0.5232, 0.4844],
        [0.5232, 0.4844],
        [0.5232, 0.4844],
        [0.5232, 0.4844]], grad_fn=<SigmoidBackward0>)

this is the output of my NN, however im not sure why it is returning 50x2, when i have the size of my output layer to 2 neurons.
My model:
class EstimatorModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self,
                 input_neurons:int,
                 hidden_neurons:int,
                 output_neurons:int):

        super().__init__()
        self.input_neurons= nn.Linear(in_features=input_neurons, out_features=hidden_neurons)
        self.hidden_neurons= nn.Linear(in_features=hidden_neurons, out_features=hidden_neurons)
        self.output_neurons= nn.Linear(in_features=hidden_neurons, out_features=output_neurons)

        # activation functions
        self.sigmoid = nn.Sigmoid()


    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.input_neurons(x)
        #x = self.relu(x)
        x = self.sigmoid(x)

        x = self.hidden_neurons(x)
        #x = self.relu(x)
        x = self.sigmoid(x)

        x = self.hidden_neurons(x)
        #x = self.relu(x)
        x = self.sigmoid(x)

        x = self.hidden_neurons(x)
        #x = self.relu(x)
        x = self.sigmoid(x)

        x = self.output_neurons(x)
        #x = self.relu(x)
        x = self.sigmoid(x)

        return x

Using MSEloss with Adam optimizer.
Training loop:
    for e in range(epochs):
        x=0
        for inputs, outputs in zip(input_data, output_data):
            inputs = stack(inputs, dim=1)
            outputs = stack(outputs, dim=1)
            #outputs = tensor(outputs

            print(outputs.shape)
            print(outputs)

            prediction:Tensor = model(inputs)
            prediction_processed = model.process_model_output(prediction)

            print(prediction.shape)
            print(prediction)

            loss = loss_func(prediction, outputs.float())

            optim.zero_grad()
            loss.backward()
            optim.step()

            quit()

            x+=1
            # comment this print statement if you dislike too much verbosity
            #print(f"[INFO] {x+1} pair completed. Loss: {loss}")

Any advice?
Tried to change the way input was passed, eg., passing normally, passing as a single tensor, finally passing as stack. No luck.
